# Non-Greedy Backwards JavaScript Regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following JavaScript regex:

```
/\!\[(.*?)\]\((.+?) \"(.*?)\"\)/g
```

Which is applied to a string like:

```
![test](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/raw/master/src/common/images/icon48.png)<br />![test](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/raw/master/src/common/images/icon48.png "test")<br />![test](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/raw/master/src/common/images/icon48.png)<br />![test](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/raw/master/src/common/images/icon48.png "test")
```

[regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/kO3aU7/1)

The issue I'm having is that there should be 4 distinct markdown tags in the search string, two of which should match, however the two matches coming back include markdown tags.

This seems to boil down to the regex parser looping through, grabbing the first possible match starting point and continuing on searching for the remainder of the match without regard to the fact there is a later possible starting point within the match.  I thought I could get around this with the non-greedy `?` modifier, however that doesn't seem to be the case.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two of the Markdown links don't have descriptions, but the description isn't optional in your regular expression.

```
/\!\[(.*?)\]\((.+?)(?: \"(.*?)\")?\)/g
```

It might be better to exclude certain characters in the link address part to avoid unintended long matches like this (although you should use an existing Markdown parser if you need robustness).

```
/\!\[(.*?)\]\(([^)]+?)(?: \"(.*?)\")?\)/g
```

Comment: Sorry, there's actually a second expression: `/\!\[(.*?)\]\((.+?)\)/` but it didn't seem relevant.  I'd love to use an existing parser, but none of them meet all the requirements I have (standard stuff like links, and formatting, also nested lists of mixed ul/ol and ol types, footnotes/references, mathematical symbols and equations, code tags both inline and block format and within nested lists, etc.)  Have most of it coded out but this one is giving me issues.

Comment: Also, I'd prefer not to have to limit parenthesis as they are valid URL characters but that might be wishful thinking.

Comment: Thanks, marking this as correct because I replaced the URL component of the top version of your regex with the URL matcher from [here](https://gist.github.com/hansifer/32bcba48c24621c2da78) minus the `^` at the start and the `$` at the end and it works great with everything I throw at it.  [Example](https://regex101.com/r/aN3yD1/1).